# How to remove guiding lines of Jgoodies from final product?

Tags: java, jgoodies

How do I remove the red lines that outline my columns and rows? They are helpful for development but they don't look good on the final product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JGoodies Forms (and now JGoodies Layout) you can configure a debug mode where the columns and rows are painted in red.

If you use the FormBuilder just do not call #debug or call #debug with false.

In PanelBuilder and other older builders you can use the FormDebugPanel as background panel. Just do not set an explict FormDebugPanel to make the debug lines disappear.